# Another Error in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and trying to do the exercises.  I think I may have found another error, but am not sure...

> Exercise 7.  In a noetherian ring $R$ in which every prime ideal is maximal, each descending chain of ideals $a_1 \supseteq a_2 \supseteq \ldots$ becomes stationary
>
> Hint: Show as in (3.4) that (0) is a product $p_1 \ldots p_r$ of prime ideals and that the chain $R \supseteq p_1 \supseteq p_1p_2 \supseteq \ldots \supseteq p_1\ldots p_r = (0)$ can be refined into a composition series.

So, my main issue is that the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ is noetherian and every prime ideal is maximal, yet the chain $$(2) \supsetneq (4) \supsetneq (8) \supsetneq \ldots \supsetneq (2^n) \supsetneq \ldots$$ Never becomes stationary.

Additionally, I don't know what (correct) statement he could be asking me to prove.  (I also realize there may well be a translational error.)  So am I reading it wrong or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (0) ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ is prime, but not maximal.  So $\mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: That makes so much more sense.  I'm just so used to seeing "Every nonzero prime ideal..." that I completely missed the subtlety.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: By the way, his hint is still not quite right anyways: in a typical Artin ring, the zero ideal is not a product of primes - that's just the nilradical! (The hint isn't useless, but it is false as stated.)

Comment: The hint is right. In a Noetherian ring, the nilradical is nilpotent. So if the nilradical is a product of primes, so is the zero ideal.